# R HTTR Add Headers not working

Tags: r, httr

I think I'm following the instructions in the documentation exactly (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) but I can't get the add_headers functionality to work. A simple example is:

```
library(httr)
res <- GET('http://www.google.com', httr::add_headers(Referer= 'https://www.google.com/'), user_agent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0'))
str(content(res)$headers)
```

The last line is supposed to print the header of the request and I am getting NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because google.com returns HTML, and `content` by default parses with `xml2` to `xml_document` which you can't index with `$headers`. And headers is a field returned by httpbin.org in JSON, but not by google.com (headers from google, as most sites will do, you can get to by `res$headers`)